# How do I create a dynamic NxM table based on HTML input using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to receive height and width values using HTML. With these values, I wish to use jQuery to dynamically create a table. I can't seem to get the table to display. Here are the pertinent parts of code:

```js
var color, height, width;// Select color input
var row, cell;
color = $('#colorPicker').val();

$('#sizePicker').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  height = $("#input_height").val();
  width = $('#input_width').val();
  makeGrid();
});

function makeGrid() {
  for(var h=0; h < height; h++){
    $("#pixel_canvas").append("<tr id='row'></tr>");
    for(var w=0; w < width; w++){
      $("#row").append("<td>Sample text</td>")
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
tr,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

tr {
    height: 20px;
}

td {
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
  <form id="sizePicker">
        Grid Height:
        <input type="number" id="input_height" name="height" min="1" value="1">
        Grid Width:
        <input type="number" id="input_width" name="width" min="1" value="1">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Pick A Color</h2>
    <input type="color" id="colorPicker">

    <h2>Design Canvas</h2>
    <table id="pixel_canvas"></table>
```

Whenever I click submit on the HTML button, the browser URL updates with the accurate numeric values, but the page doesn't display anything. I've also written the table manually using HTML. I saw it display, so I know my CSS shouldn't be a problem. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For ids to be useful, they must be unique.

Repeated `<tr id='row'>` leads to table rows that cannot be reliably selected by id, but fortunately you don't need to do so.

Instead, keep a reference in javascript to the appended row.

```
$('#sizePicker input').on('change', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var height = +$("#input_height").val();
    var width = +$('#input_width').val();
    makeGrid(width, height);
});

function makeGrid(width, height) {
    var $row;
    for(var h=0; h < height; h++) {
        $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo('#pixel_canvas'); // <<< assign reference to the appended <tr/>
        for(var w=0; w < width; w++) {
            $row.append("<td>Sample text</td>"); // <<< use reference to the appended <tr/>
        }
    }
}
```

And you don't need a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the height and width as parameters because they are not in the same scope.

```
var color, height, width;// Select color input
var row, cell;
color = $('#colorPicker').val();

$('#sizePicker').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  height = $("#input_height").val();
  width = $('#input_width').val();
  makeGrid(height ,width);
});

function makeGrid(height, width) {
  for(var h=0; h < height; h++){
    $("#pixel_canvas").append("<tr id='row'>");
    for(var w=0; w < width; w++){
      $("#pixel_canvas").append("<td>Sample text</td>")
    }
    $("#pixel_canvas").append("</tr>");
  }
}
```

that should work.

Comment: i worked for bro, i tried it on my computer. i wouldnt give an answer without trying it. thank you though

Comment: You are still relying on `$("#row")`!

Comment: you're right bro, but in his question he mentioned that the table does not get  displayed on the page, that's what i tried to reply for.

Comment: i figured out another problem which is that he open the tr and close it immediately before inserting any td inside. `$("#pixel_canvas").append("<tr id='row'></tr>");`

Comment: You probably tested in Chrome. Try running your code in IE. The result will be quite different.

Comment: You're making it worse not better.

Comment: You're inserting DOM nodes here, not building HTML. Big difference.

Comment: I tried both methods guys. Sorry, but neither worked for me. I am using Chrome.